# Are there any tools can be used to manage smart card resources?

Tags: smartcard, javacard

Are there any tools can be used to manage smart card resources, can use it to debug command ISO14443 agreement.

Comment: Managing resources, debugging and analyzing contactless communication are quite separate functions. Which of these are you asking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pyResMan is a free open source smartcard tool for JavaCard and other smart card. It can be used to send APDU(s), execute APDU script(s); It can be used to debug ISO14443 protocol commands and Mifare commands with R502 SPY reader; It can also be used to manage resource of GP card, It is based on pyScard and GlobalPlatform open source projects.

Comment: Where can i get it or can you give me a link to it ? I want to have a try.

Comment: “https://github.com/JavaCardOS/pyResMan” A link to the pyResMan.you can try it.